# Is it possible to define codepage for tangled file while Org-mode tangle?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, tangle

Subj. I want to tangle file to be in different codepage than viewed Org file.
Didn't find any header agruments for encoding :(

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to tangle into a specific encoding such as `utf-8-unix` versas `iso 8859-14`?

Comment: similar. Org file is in `UTF-8`, tangled file should be in `win1251`